# Unable to load fields when certain option is selected (semantic ui and jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I have a semantic ui dropdown when I select 'select categories' option it should load another dropdown(select category). If I do not select anything then it should not load this other dropdown. I tried using hide and show but I am not getting correct output. Please suggest how this can be done.

[image]

HTML code:-

```
 <div class="ui icon top left pointing dropdown button blue" id="dropdown1">
                <i class="sort content descending icon"></i>
                  <span class="text">Advance Filter</span>
                 <div class="menu">
                  <div class="header">All Categories</div>
                  <div class="item">Select Categories</div>
                </div>
                </div>

          <select id="category" name="activity-filter" multiple="" class="ui dropdown" style="display:none;">
             <i class="filter icon"></i>
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
        <option class="header">--All--</option>
        <option value="0">rst</option>
        <option value="1">lmn</option>
        <option value="2">abc</option>
        <option value="3">pqr</option>
        <option value="12">Other</option> 
      </select>  

      <button class="ui primary button">
        Submit
      </button>

      <button class="ui button show-all">
        Clear
      </button>
      <br>
      <br>
```

jquery:-

```
<script>
$('#dropdown1').dropdown(
  {
 onChange: function(val) {

   if(val=='select categories')
   {
    $('#category').show();
   }
  else
  {
    $('#category').hide();
  }
 }
}
);
</script>
```

Comment: It seems to work without any modification?

Comment: It's not working, I want the select category dropdown to be visible on page only when select category is selected from advacnced filter dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted your code in as you provided above - it seems to function correctly?

```js
$('#dropdown1').dropdown(
  {
 onChange: function(val) {

   if(val=='select categories')
   {
    $('#category').show();
   }
  else
  {
    $('#category').hide();
  }
 }
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui icon top left pointing dropdown button blue" id="dropdown1">
                <i class="sort content descending icon"></i>
                  <span class="text">Advance Filter</span>
                 <div class="menu">
                  <div class="header">All Categories</div>
                  <div class="item">Select Categories</div>
                </div>
                </div>

          <select id="category" name="activity-filter" multiple="" class="ui dropdown" style="display:none;">
             <i class="filter icon"></i>
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
        <option class="header">--All--</option>
        <option value="0">rst</option>
        <option value="1">lmn</option>
        <option value="2">abc</option>
        <option value="3">pqr</option>
        <option value="12">Other</option> 
      </select>  

      <button class="ui primary button">
        Submit
      </button>

      <button class="ui button show-all">
        Clear
      </button>
      <br>
      <br>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing complete code!! I was using version 2.2.4 for semantic ui script and when I changed to 13 it worked.

Comment: But why the design of dropdown has changed. It is not coming as dropdown now and has scroller. How can I correct it? Please suggset

Comment: You need to set #category as a dropdown in the JS... see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/w79sLpL9/1/